# Does a "with" statement support type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Can you define the type hint for a variable defined with the `with` syntax?

```py
with example() as x:
    print(x)
```

I would like to type hint the above to say that `x` is a `str` (as an example).

The only work around that I've found is to use an intermediate variable, but this feels hacky.

```py
with example() as x:
    y: str = x
    print(y)
```

I can't find an example in the [typing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: Shouldnt type checkers be able to deduce the type of `x` as the return type of `example().__enter__()`?

Comment: Why do you want to annotate `x` when it's is simply the return type of `example.__enter__`? Ideally you have annotated that method / function.

Comment: `x` isn't the return value of `example`; it's the return value of `example().__enter__()`.

Comment: Most methods I've found don't define a type hint for the return value.

Comment: `str` wasn't the best example of a type to use here as it's not a resource, but you get the idea behind the question.

Comment: @Reactgular Then the solution is to create a [stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) for that function, so the type checker can infer the type. Usually you annotate at the API boundaries, not inside. In this case it's clear the type comes from `example`. Annotating `example.__enter__` means one annotation while with your approach you would have to annotate in *all* places where that context manager is used, plus in general how is a user supposed to know what the return type of an API is anyway if it isn't supplied?

Comment: @a_guest thank you. I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Reactgular Does PEP 526 work for you? My text editor seems to accept `x: str` before or after the `with` line.

Comment: @pschill I'm using PyCharm. Can you give an example of what works for you?

Comment: @Reactgular `x: str; with example() as x: print(x)` seems to work in PyCharm. This also works with proper formatting instead of the semicolon.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[PEP 526](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/), which has been implemented in Python 3.6, allows you to annotate variables. The variable used in a `with` statement can be annotated like this:

```
x: str
with example() as x:
    [...]
```

Comment: This also works for other code blocks like `for`. Great answer, thank you.

Comment: If the context manager doesn't hint what the `__enter__` method will return, typing `x` doesn't serve any purpose. `mypy` will happily allow a value of any type to be bound to `x`.

Comment: @chepner Yes you are right. PyCharm recognizes `x` as `str` in both cases, but `mypy` does not.

Comment: I get error `Name "x" already defined on line` by mypy for second example

Comment: @cikatomo You are right, I edited my answer and removed the second example. Seems to be a case of [Where annotations aren't allowed](https://peps.python.org/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed)

Answer (score 16):

Usually type annotations are placed at the API boundaries. In this case the type should be inferred from `example.__enter__`. In case that function doesn't declare any types, the solution is to create a corresponding [stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) in order to help the type checker infer that type.

Specifically this means creating a `.pyi` file with the same stem as the module from which `Example` was imported. Then the following code can be added:

```
class Example:
    def __enter__(self) -> str: ...
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback) -> None: ...
```

Comment: This one will fail miserably if `class Example` is inherited from some contextlib other class
As these define `def __enter__(self) -> Self` so you now can never return anything other than self. Which is needed in 99% cases