# Python 'with' statement declare variable type

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to declare the variable 'type' when using a Python `with` clause, specifically when creating an SQLAlchemy session.

In the below code snippet, the 'type' of the created `session` variable is not auto-detected  so the `session.add(...)` and `session.commit(...)` statements can't be auto-completed based on the `sqlalchemy.orm.Session` class.

Code snippet:

```
with create_session(bind=self.db_engine) as session:
    user = User(
        name="John"
    )

    session.add(John)
    session.commit()
```

Is there a way to do this in-line in Python (3.8.11)? without making a statement like this:

```
with create_session(bind=self.db_engine) as session:
    session: Session = session
    ...
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169996/does-a-with-statement-support-type-hinting